# maximo to blender riggify rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, .fbx

there is a character I have rigged and I used expy kit to add mixamo animation to it. I uploaded fbx to Mixamo and got my animation but whenever I bind the fbx to the active armeture the eyes wont change location. please guide me if you are familiar with this case.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.